# Choosing image from windows phone media library and set as page background

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, uri, media-library

I am trying to retrieve an image from the phone library and set it as the page background using the following code

```
    private void selectImageFromMediaLib()
    {
         selectphoto = new PhotoChooserTask();
         selectphoto.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(selectphoto_Completed);
     selectphoto.Show();
    }

    private void selectphoto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            backgroundUri = new Uri(e.OriginalFileName, UriKind.Absolute);
            var bitmap = new BitmapImage(backgroundUri);
            ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
            imageBrush.ImageSource = bitmap;
            this.LayoutRoot.Background = imageBrush;     
     }
    }
```

However, the page background turns black so the photo was not retrieved/created correctly. What is the correct path for the URI to the device library? Isn't using `UriKind.Absolute` enough?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the [PhotoResult.OriginalFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photoresult.originalfilename%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property to read the file, instead use the 
[PhotoResult.ChosenPhoto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photoresult.chosenphoto%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) stream and assign it to the `bitmap.ImageSource` property in your code.

Answer (score 0):

try this. It works for me

```
PhotoChooserTask selectphoto;
private void selectImageFromMediaLib()
{
   selectphoto = new PhotoChooserTask();
   selectphoto.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(selectphoto_Completed);
   selectphoto.Show();
}

private void selectphoto_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
   if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
   {
       var imageBytes = new byte[e.ChosenPhoto.Length];
       e.ChosenPhoto.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
       BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
       bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
       ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
       imageBrush.ImageSource = bitmapImage;
       this.LayoutRoot.Background = imageBrush;
    }
}
```